# If elif one liner

Tags: python-3.x

```
if i == len(a):
   tempList.extend(b[j:])
   break
elif j == len(b):
   tempList.extend(a[i:])
   break
```

I am using this in a mergesort-program in Python. Is there any way to put this into a oneliner?

Comment: Just because you asked for it: `tempList.extend(b[j:]) if i == len(a) else tempList.extend(a[i:]) if j == len(b) else None` but please, for  the love of the Python gods, don't use it. Also keep in mind it doesn't have the break logic your original code has.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you for the answer! Just wanted an opinion, and you gave it :D

Answer (score 7):

Maybe, but let's give a dedicated non-answer: don't even try.

You don't write your code to be **short**. You write it so that:

- it gets the job done in a straight forward manner
- it clearly communicates its meaning to **human** readers

The above code does that already.

In other words: of course being *precise* is a valuable property of source code. So, when you have to *equally* readable pieces of code doing the same thing, and one version is a one-liner, and the other is way more lengthy - then you go for the short version.

But I very much doubt that the above can be expressed *as readable* as above - with less code.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `and` and `or` [boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to make a pretty readable one-liner:

```
l = []
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [8,9,10]
i = 4
j = 2

l.extend(i == len(a) and b[j:] or j == len(b) and a[i:] or [])
l == [10]

i = 0
j = 3

l.extend(i == len(a) and b[j:] or j == len(b) and a[i:] or [])
l == [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This example uses next properties:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

We have to add `or []` to mitigate `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` exception raised when `i == len(a) and j > len(b)` (e.g. `i == 4 and j == 5`).

---

I'd still prefer an expanded version though.